# Certificate unknown while making a request with hackney even when passing insecure option

Tags: ssl, erlang, elixir

I am attempting to make a call to an API I am developing using Hackney.

This API is a rails app, for develpment I am using nginx and passenger to serve it, and I generated a CA Certificate and Host certificate using `etcd_ca`. I've installed the CA certificate in my linux box and neither curl, chrome or firefox complaint about the certificate.

But when I attempt to make a request with Hackney I get this error:

```
hackney:request(Method, Uri, Headers, Body, [insecure]).


18:43:15.720 [error] SSL: :certify: ssl_handshake.erl:415:Fatal error: certificate unknown

** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:tls_alert, 'certificate unknown'}}
    (omnitutor_rt) lib/omnitutor_rt/api_client.ex:49: OmnitutorRT.APIClient.request/3
    (omnitutor_rt) lib/omnitutor_rt/api_client.ex:7: OmnitutorRT.APIClient.get_session/2
```

In staging and development I have a valid certificate.

I am running Arch Linux, Elixir 1.2 and Erlang 18.

```
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Linux 4.4.1-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 3 13:12:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

etcd-ca uses this templates to generate the certificates:

https://github.com/coreos/etcd-ca/blob/master/Documentation/certificate_template.md

Could this be related?
http://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-33

Comment: I would try to set the certificate (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816945/erlang-needs-to-connect-to-https-server/34819176#34819176).

Comment: I have already tried, An additional message is logged before the same error is raised `[info]  [83, 83, 76, 32, 87, 65, 82, 78, 73, 78, 71, 58, ...]` So I assume the CA file is being read.

Comment: I do believe it'd help people to advise you if you posted the versions of the various pieces of software involved. For example, which OS (with version), which version of Elixir, which version of Erlang etc. etc. etc.  There was a known problem with SSL in Erlang not that long ago but without a version there's no way to tell if that's it in this case.

Comment: I added OS, Elixir and Erlang info

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this error, we have a file name and line number:

```
ssl_handshake.erl:415:Fatal error: certificate unknown
```

And [reading the source](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.0/lib/ssl/src/ssl_handshake.erl#L412-L416) we see that this happens when an error is caught, either from `ssl_certificate:trusted_cert_and_path` or `public_key:pkix_path_validation`.  Unfortunately, we don't get to see the actual error information.

The best way to figure out what's going wrong is probably to trace those two functions.  This is what you'd type in an Erlang shell; the Elixir version should be similar:

```
%% start the tracer
dbg:tracer().
%% trace function _c_alls for _all_ processes
dbg:p(all,c).
%% add a _t_race _p_attern for the relevant functions,
%% and look for e_x_ceptions
dbg:tp(ssl_certificate, trusted_cert_and_path, x).
dbg:tp(public_key, pkix_path_validation, x).
```